# Problem with NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm quite a rookie when  it comes to Cocoa programming, so I hope some experts can hint me on the right direction with a problem I'm facing.

I have a NSCollectionView that is bound to a NSArrayController (A) of elements having two properties: an URL to a picture and a NSArray (B) of elements of another class.
For every element inside the NSArrayController (A) , I load a subview with a NSImageView that should display the image in the URL and a NSTableView that is bound to the elements of the NSArray (B).

Everything works fine, except for one very important thing: the URL to the picture is not immediately available when I create the subview, it becomes available later, but when it does, I don't see the picture loading in the NSImageView.
I would think of a problem in the KVC/KVO implementation, but the strange thing is that the image loads correctly if, when the URL becomes available, the subview is not visible (e.g in a portion of the scrollview that is not displayed).

Example: The NSScrollview size is such that it can display only two subviews at a time. I add three elements to the NSArrayController (A): the first two images don't load, if I scroll down the scrollview to see the third element, I find the image loaded correctly.

Any ideas about what could cause such a strange behaviour?
Thank you in advance

Luca

*series.h*

```
@interface Series : NSObject {
@private
NSMutableString * banner;
}
-(Series*)initWithEpisode:(Episode*)ep;
-(void)setBanner:(NSString*)_banner;
@property (retain, readwrite) NSMutableString *banner;
@end
```

*series.m*

```
@implementation Series
@synthesize banner;
-(Series*)initWithEpisode:(Episode*)ep
{
self = [super init];
if(self){
banner = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"some invalid URL"];
}
-(void) setBanner:(NSString*)_banner
{
[banner setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some root path/%@", _banner];
}
-(void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
[banner release];
}
```

*SeriesListViewController.m*

```
-(void)VideoChangedStatus:(Episode*)ep{
//This is the delegate called by the object Episode when it retrieves the URL via asynchronous call to a webservice
Series *tmp = [[Series alloc]initWithEpisode:ep];
[[seriesList objectAtIndex:[seriesList indexOfObject:tmp]]setBanner:[ep banner]];
}
```

The binding is done in the subview nib file, to the NSImageView: I set File's Owner of type NSCollectionViewItem and then bind Valueurl to representedObject.banner
I didn't subclass NSCollectionView nor NSCollectionViewItem

Comment: Describe how you "load the image". Exactly what happens when the URL becomes available? How do you update your model (a KVO-notifying property)? How do you update your view (bindings?).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The urlvalue property of the NSImageView is bound to a NSMutableString called "banner". When URL becomes available banner value is changed to the new URL through a method called setBanner

Comment: Insufficient information. Describe the binding *completely* - every aspect - for clarity. Describe the "banner" property *completely* (is it an Objective-C 2.0 @property with @synthesize accessors or a custom accessor? To what object does that property belong? Is this object stored in the array controller or somewhere else?). HELP US HELP YOU.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I didn't have the code at hand but I hoped that the "symptom" would ring a bell.
I added some sample code and more information to the thread.
Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of trying I found a solution that works: apparently it's not enough to use the setString method, I need to re-intialize the property inside the setBanner method

```
-(void) setBanner:(NSString*)_banner  
 {
     banner = [NSMutableString[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some root path/%@", _banner]];  
 }
```

Still, I'd be very glad to know if someone has an explanation of why setString was causing that strange (to me) problem and why this solution works.

Thank you
Luca

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure why you’ve declared `banner` to be a mutable string — it looks like an immutable string would suffice.

At any rate, when you write a custom setter method you need to send `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` to ensure KVO (and hence bindings) compliance:

```
-(void) setBanner:(NSString*)_banner
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"banner"];
    [banner setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some root path/%@", _banner];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"banner"];

}
```